# Multiple file upload using javascript without modifying current code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script already for uploading pictures, but I want the ability to select more pictures at once on upload,by holding down ctrl,I know I can use uploadify but I don't want to start over, mabe you guys know a script or something for jquery, that will work without to remove the current code, or you guys could give me a snippet.

Comment: So, change everything, but don't change anything at all? if your script isn't expecting multiple files, then nothing you do on the client side will ever change that fact. Don't be lazy and update the server-side code.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to slect multiple files in entirely the browsers features. Which cannot be changed by using a `Javascript` or `css` or `html`. Using uploadify or similar as you mentioned in your question is the right way to go.

You know `uploadify` also uses the `swfobject.js`, to overcome this limitation by using an `actionscript` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own upload system in javascript with ajax. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Basic workflow

- get local file contents
- push to server via ajax

With this you could do a multi-file select and/or drag and drop upload system. Best and maybe only solution if you want to stay in javascript.